# smptlib не отправляется письмо с mail.ru

Tags: python, email, smtp, smtplib

Не отправляется письмо, при этом ошибки никакой нет, программа продолжается работать, но ничего не происходит. Еще зависает когда пытаешься ее остановить. Кусок кода:

```
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = cfg.USER
msg['To'] = message.text
msg['Subject'] = "Привет от питона"

body = "Это пробное сообщение"
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
server = smtplib.SMTP(cfg.SERVER, cfg.PORT)
server.starttls()
server.login(cfg.USER, cfg.PASSWORD)
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(cfg.USER, message.text, text)
server.quit()
```

В самом мэил ру включил Imap, получил пароль для внешних приложений (он и используется). Порт стоит 465. Я знаю, что smtplib не очень дружит с мэйлом, что адрес есть и хочется его использовать

UPD: спустя некоторое время вылетает ошибка:

> smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed

UPD 2: Попробовал поменять соединение на SSL, поставил порт 25, как рекомендуется в одном гайде. Теперь ошибка:

> ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:992)

Comment: Порт 465 и starttls — это взаимоисключаемые вещи, оставьте только что-нибудь одно (например, уберите starttls)

Comment: @andreymal убрал, тоже самое

Comment: А если вы используете порт 25, то наоборот верните starttls обратно

Comment: Ах да, я ещё забыл добавить, что для порта 465 вместо `smtplib.SMTP` нужно использовать `smtplib.SMTP_SSL`

Comment: @andreymal перепробовал разные варианты и с 465, и с 25 портом (там вообще ужас начинается), в итоге работает только такой вариант - `server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(cfg.SERVER, 465)` Ну как работает - программа завершается успешно, чертово письмо не приходит :(

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать 587 порт, через него я успешно отправил письмо на mail почту, или заменить строку с  SMTP_SSL на

```py
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.mail.ru', 465)
```

Если это не работает советую использовать библиотеку [social-spam](https://pypi.org/project/social-spam/).